# How to simulate soft ground in webots？

Tags: webots

My robot is a  Skid-Steered mobile robot ,which built in the soft sand, so I need to verify the dynamics of my wheeled mobile robot in the soft sand, that is, I want to give a torque to the wheels motor to check the movement of the robot, but I don't know how to simulate the situation of the soft sand in webots, please help to give me a solution,thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We did something similar for the RoboCup simulation:
https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/pull/2831#issuecomment-797423633

Basically, you can set the `softCFM` parameter to like 0.03.

The `softCFM` parameter is a parameter of the [ContactProperties](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/contactproperties) node. Note that you have to add the `ContactProperties` node to the [WorlInfo](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/worldinfo) > `contactProperties`.